# Programming dependencies/relationships in python

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am designing a class in python whose properties have a mesh of interdepencies.

Say like it has a property A. When A is set to True then  properties B and C can be used. Or else they cant be used. Property B and C may be of any type. May be a boolean or int or string or any custom class.

Also say if B is enabled then we can have either properties D or E or F ( a checkbox like behaviour).

How do i design such dependencies in python class?.

Also i may have similar classes which have such dependencies.. So i am thinking of making a metaclass or baseclass or template like design where user will specify dependencies and code is internally generated.

Any design inputs on how to proceed?

Comment: Use the @property tag and control access. That should be possible in python.

Comment: how to control access?? By explicitly writing if else inside the property method? i want to avoid that..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "designing dependencies", but I'd just give the class some methods decorated with the `@property` tag that check `self.a` and `self.b` prior to returning some value.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @property
    def b():
        return "b" if self.a else None

    @property
    def c():
        return "c" if self.a else None

    @property
    def d():
        return "d" if self.b else None

    @property
    def e():
        return "e" if self.b else None

    @property
    def f():
        return "f" if self.b else None
```

Comment: Hi Alex.. Yes i want something like this.. But i dont want to write the code for if else manually every time.. i wanted some base class to take  the dependecies mentioned in some format(say a plain python expression) and constructs this code for me..

Comment: I suppose there's no harm in splitting these properties up amongst multiple classes, as the inherited classes will inherit properties from the base class.